# Spa/hot tub A/C pump hums, but does not run

Tags: pump, hot-tub

When I turn on the power to my hot tub at the breaker, I can hear the relays closing and the pump hums for a short while, but it doesn't turn.

I recently drained and filled my hot tub.  After refilling, I ran the pump for a few minutes to circulate some chemicals, so it was working at the time.  I then turned off the power at the breaker to check something.  Then, when I turned the power back on, the pump wouldn't start.  The control panel lights up.  I can hear the relays click in the control box, and hear a humming for a few seconds (the pump trying to start, maybe, it's hard to tell) then the humming stops.

I read that air in the pump can prevent priming.  However, the pump did run for a few minutes after we refilled the hot tub, so I don't think it's air in the line.  Just to be sure I loosened the outlet connector on the pump and water drained out, in hopes that any air would be released

The control box unit has two fuses labeled pump 1 and pump 2, and I've checked and they're both good.

The pump connects to the control box via a specialized plug, and I'm sure it's well connected.

- Maybe the capacitor on the pump went out? As I indicated, it's probably 10 years old. How do you troubleshoot that?
- Something jamming the pump from turning? How can you check that?
- Anything else?

**Update 1**  Replaced the capacitor and it ran for a short while but stopped again.  I've removed the pump and will test it on a bench.

**Update 2** After pulling the motor out I confirmed that the impeller could be easily turned by hand, so it wasn't jammed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After pulling the motor out (which required draining the spa and disconnecting the PVC connections) and removing the cover, I found another capacitor. Googling the part number indicates that this is a **start capacitor**.  It helps the motor start.

The motor also has a capacitor on the outside, and it's the **run capacitor**.  That's the one that was replaced first.

After replacing the **start capacitor**, the motor started and is running.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_capacitor

It turns out that Spa/hot rub AC motors like this have **both** a **start** and **run capacitor**, as do blowers on forced air furnaces and air conditioning units.  If an AC motor like this won't start, there's a good chance it's the start capacitor. The start capacitors tend to fail eventually, the run capacitors last much longer, apparently.

**My spa motor**

[image: Spa motor]

**Start capacitor**

[image: Start capacitor]

**Run capacitor**

[image: Run capacitor]

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer comes in one of the three things you've already stated: 1) bad pump motor; 2) capacitor; 3) impeller jammed.

In your case I believe the problem is with the motor (as you've probably already figured out).

- You've already replaced the capacitor. If this were truly the problem, it would have fixed it more than allowing to run for just a moment or two (obviously).
- If the impeller was jammed with something, changing the capacitor would have had absolutely no effect on it.
- The description you provided sounds exactly like what an electric motor does when it's going out ... it stalls with a hum.

Comment: One or both brushes may be worn to a nub, or busted and blocking the rotor after ten years use.